# php check value in a foreach if match output the value after the match line

Tags: php, foreach

Some easy code, If I have a json data. I want do somethings, first check the `match string` in the json data, if have, output the value after the match line, else output all the json data.

Exapmle 1, match string is 9, match in the json data, output the value after the match line 7, 3.

```
$txt = '[{"a":"5"},{"a":"9"},{"a":"7"},{"a":"3"}]';
$array = json_decode($txt);
$match_string = '9';
foreach ($array as $data){      
    echo $data->a;//7, 3
}
```

Exapmle 2, match string is 2, not match in the json data, output all the value, 5, 9, 7, 3.

```
$txt = '[{"a":"5"},{"a":"9"},{"a":"7"},{"a":"3"}]';
$array = json_decode($txt);
$match_string = '2';
foreach ($array as $data){      
    echo $data->a;//5, 9, 7, 3
}
```

How to do this judgment? I do something like in the foreach, just ignore the match string:

```
if($match_string == $data->a){
  continue;//fut this in the foreach ,get 5, 7, 3, but I need 7, 3, next value from 9.
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a flag telling you whether or not you've found a match:

```
$txt = '[{"a":"5"},{"a":"9"},{"a":"7"},{"a":"3"}]';
$array = json_decode($txt);
$match_string = "2";
$found = false;
foreach ($array as $data) {
    if ($found) {
        echo $data->a;
    } else if ($data->a === $match_string) {
        // If we set $found *after* we have the opportunity to display it,
        // we'll have to wait until the next pass.
        $found = true;
    }
}
if (!$found) {
    // Display everything
    foreach ($array as $data) {
        echo $data->a;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing brace for the if clause.  Also, it seems to me he doesn't actually want to print the matched value...

Comment: prefer this answer as @FrankieTheKneeMan implies to much knowledge of precedence order :-)

Comment: @arxanas, see your edit code, that's right, just do `$array = json_decode($txt);//move true`, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To make it shorter.

```
$txt = '[{"a":"5"},{"a":"9"},{"a":"7"},{"a":"3"}]';
$array = json_decode($txt);
$toFind = "9";
$mapped = array_map("current",$array);

if (!in_array($toFind,$mapped))
    echo implode(", ",$mapped);
else
    echo implode(", ",array_slice($mapped,array_search($toFind,$mapped)+1));
```

Note that you won't preserve keys with that function
Edited for performance

Comment: +1 because this is a cool solution, and by writing your own mapping method, you could easily generalize this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$matched = false;
foreach($array as $data){
    if($matched)
        echo $data->a;
    $matched = ($data->a==$matchString) || $matched;
}
if(!$matched)
    foreach($array as $data)
        echo $data->a;
```

That's your base case.

Comment: I have to say that this is not very reasonable code. `$data->a == $matchString` is one thing, but `$data->a == $matchString || $matched`...? I don't even remember the orders of precedence here.

Comment: Equality has higher precedence than boolean joins.  Always, in any language, ever.  If it bothers you, though... ($data->a==$matchString) || $matched  ... the fix is as easy as two parentheses.

Comment: @arxanas  Actually, in most languages you get Parentheses, Unary Operators, Multiplication/Division, Addition/Subtraction, Comparison, And/Or.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work, provided $txt is an ordered list and not an array dictionary (sorry; I was apparently hallucinating).

```
<?php
    $txt = '[{"a":"5"},{"a":"9"},{"a":"7"},{"a":"3"}]';
    $array = json_decode($txt);
    $match_string = '9';

    $found = false;
    foreach ($array as $data)
    {
        if ($found) // Line before was lucky
        {
            print $data->a;
            break;
        }
        if ($data->a == $match_string)
            $found = true;
    }
    if (!$found)
    {
        // Output the whole object
    }
?>
```

Still it is unclear what ought to happen when the desired match is the last entry in the array. What WOULD happen is that nothing gets output, since the row has been found but has no successors.